# Where is `defaults -currentHost write domain key value` written to?

Tags: system-settings, defaults

When I use `defaults write domain key value` the information is written to `~/Library/Preferences/domain.plist`.

When I use the `-currentHost` flag, it has a higher priority then when I just use `defaults` without a specified host.

But where is the value actually written to? It is consistent between system startups, so it must be somewhere on the disk...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `-currentHost` with `defaults` it acts on `.plist` files in:

```
$HOME/Library/Preferences/ByHost/
```

As an example, I did not have a `com.apple.finder` *plist* file at that location and when I executed the following command, one was created at that location.

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.finder GoToField "/foobar"
```

---

```
$ defaults -currentHost read com.apple.finder GoToField
/foobar
$
```

---

Note the full file name contains a UUID however you do not need to include it when `-currentHost` is used, the normal naming is all that's needed as shown in the command line above.

Example: `$HOME/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.finder.6966D045-28DC-544A-97C2-98CDB668DC8B.plist`